# Click "featured php questions feed" opens XML file

Tags: support, rss

So I was looking around the recent PHP questions and I saw a button, **featured php questions feed**, as shown here:

[image: Link I clicked]

On click, it opened this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=php&sort=featured) - And it opened what seemed to be pure HTML and PHP, JS, etc...
I thought it was some code you put on your site, but SO would have a better way to display that, then I was looking at the code and there was some PHP fatal errors, here's the [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/CapbZcji).

Sorry if this is normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your browser, and other applications on your computer what happens; this is just the format to distribute [RSS feed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS) information.

That it includes PHP errors is just because the Stack Overflow questions in it are about those errors; the Java feed won't have them. The Stack Exchange network is built with .NET and doesn't use PHP.

Comment: Oh god... I feel really stupid now but thanks a lot for letting me know :~)

Comment: Do you think I should leave the question (**I didn't see any duplicates**)

Comment: I think the question is fine; there might be more people not knowing about RSS feeds, and without knowing the term it is hard to search for it.

Comment: Yeah, I thought the same thing :-)